# PANDAS dataframe python: wanting to sort values by group

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, series

[Link to census data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Qian-Han/coursera-Applied-Data-Science-with-Python/master/Introduction-to-Data-Science-in-Python/original_data/census.csv)

I have the following link above for a CSV file containing the raw data for which I wish to manipulate.

```
census_df = df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Qian-Han/coursera-Applied-Data-Science-with-Python/master/Introduction-to-Data-Science-in-Python/original_data/census.csv')
sortedit = census_df.sort_values(by = ['STNAME','CENSUS2010POP'],ascending=False)
```

I am trying to order the data in descending order by the column **'CENSUS2010POP'.**

I also want to order the data by 'state' alphabetically, hence why I have including the **'STNAME'** column in the formula above.

However, I only want to select the **3 highest values** for **'CENSUS2010POP'**  from each state ('STNAME').

Thus, if there are 146 states in total, I should (146 x 3) rows in my new dataframe (and thus in the 'CENSUS2010POP' column).

I would be so grateful if anybody could give me a helping hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
df = census_df.groupby(["STNAME"]).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(["CENSUS2010POP"], ascending = False)).reset_index(drop=True)

df.groupby('STNAME').head(3)[['STNAME','CENSUS2010POP']]
```

The first statement returns dataframe sorted by `CENSUS2010POP` in each `STNAME`.

The second statement returns the top 3.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, `groupby` with `.nalrgest` to create an index filter, chained with `sort_values`

```
df2 = df.iloc[df.groupby('STNAME')['CENSUS2010POP']\
                              .nlargest(3).index.get_level_values(1)]\
                              .sort_values(['STNAME','CENSUS2010POP'],ascending=True)

print(df['STNAME'].nunique())

51


print(df2.shape)
(152, 100)
```

---

```
print(df2[['STNAME','CENSUS2010POP']])

   STNAME  CENSUS2010POP
49      Alabama         412992
37      Alabama         658466
0       Alabama        4779736
76       Alaska          97581
71       Alaska         291826
...         ...            ...
3137  Wisconsin         947735
3096  Wisconsin        5686986
3182    Wyoming          75450
3180    Wyoming          91738
3169    Wyoming         563626

[152 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: I have not checked the answer yet, but my overall code now looks like this: 

def answer_six():
df = census_df.groupby(["STNAME"]).apply(lambda x:         x.sort_values(["CENSUS2010POP"], ascending =   False)).reset_index(drop=True)
df.groupby('STNAME').head(3)[['STNAME','CENSUS2010POP']]
df.sort_values(["CENSUS2010POP"],ascending=False)
df = df[0:3]
return df['STNAME']

So effectively, it will return the name of the 3 states with the largest values for 'CENSUS2010POP'. 

It is giving me: California, Texas, New York :)

Comment: I Would avoid the apply as it should only be used as a last resort when can't use any of the api methods to re-shape your data.There are native methods to handle your questions which will work faster and be more scale-able. @Caledonian26